# rpm: how to disable debuginfo

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

OS RedHat 8.4

I know that having `%debug_package` macro in a `spec` file will generate debuginfo for a package, and will produce `mypackage-debuginfo-<VERSION>.<ARCH>` rpm. However the funny thing is that `spec` file I have does not have this macro and yet the debuginfo is built.

However, at the top of the `spec` file there is a few global variables:

```
%global _hardened_build 1
%global sysrepo 0
%undefine _missing_build_ids_terminate_build
%define _unpackaged_files_terminate_build 0
```

I wonder if one of them enables `%debug_package` macro?

Comment: I'd be curious if debug_package macro is being set in one of your RC files; what does `rpm --showrc | grep debug_package` show?

Comment: It is defined in `rpm --showrc` output, so setting `%define debug_package %{nil}` in the spec file helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

rpm macro definitions are loaded in order, so your best options seem to be:

1. override it in the RPM -- for disabling debuginfo RPM creation of that RPM
2. override it in your `~/.rpmrc` -- for disabling debuginfo creation for RPMs built under your account
3. override it in `/etc/rpm/macros` or `/etc/rpmrc` -- for disabling debuginfo creation for RPMs built on that system.

The `__debug_package 1` definition on my system is set in /usr/lib/rpm/macros, so any RC file that's read after that should work (including the RPM file itself).